# Translate Windows System Error Codes in Java

Tags: java, windows, error-code

Is there a preferred way in Java to lookup the error message identified by a Windows error code, as listed on this web page:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx

I know in C/C++ you can use FormatMessage(...). Is there some operation to lookup system error codes from Java?

Comment: Not without using JNI / JNA (at least not that I'm aware of.) Can't you just call the relevant DLL function using JNA? (I'm assuming that portability isn't a requirement considering we're talking about Windows specific error codes.)

Comment: You're right, that is a possibility. I was just wondering whether there existes a Java framework operations that translates these operating system codes. Apparently not.